# triggering keypress event on textarea not working jquery fiddle

Tags: jquery, triggers, textarea

1) I have a `textarea` where I'm executing a function to autosize it after writing on it.... (it works well)

2) I have a button that it changes the `class` of the textarea, after clicking on it (add bg color, padding,etc.)

**PROBLEM**

After clicking on the button, Everything works well, but the `padding-bottom`  appers to be `0`  When it is supossed to show new `40px` padding bottom. this padding is only restored after writing someting on the textarea....

I know this is because of this `autosize function` I added to the textarea

As a solution I wanted to trigger a `.trigger("keypress");` after clicking the button but nothing

What am I doing wrong?

```js
$('textarea').on('input', autosize);

function autosize() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this
    .css({
      height: 'auto'
    })
    .css({
      height: $this.prop('scrollHeight')
    });
}

$(".BgChanger").on("click", function() {

  $(".main_textarea")
  .addClass("BgA");

});
```

```css
.BgChanger {}

.BgA {
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: green!important;
  text-align: center!important;
  font-size: 22px!important;
  color: white!important;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 50px 20px 40px 20px;
}

.main_textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.main_textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 90px;
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  resize: none!important;
  background: #fff;
  outline: 0;
  color: #292F33 !important;
  font-size: 20px !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="BgChanger">Change Textarea Bg</div>
<textarea class="main_textarea"></textarea>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n651hL8k/10/

Comment: After clicking on the button the padding-bottom is still 40px, the height of the area becomes 0. After writing something on it the height is restored.

Comment: how do I fix this error?

Comment: I posted an answer. As a side note, you could edit your answer to include your code, I am not sure why you said you couldn't post it here, did you try? What was the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the padding but the textarea's **height** property.

One *hacky* solution will be to chain `.css({height: 'auto'})` to your onclick handler function.

```js
$('textarea').on('input', autosize);

function autosize() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this
    .css({
      height: 'auto'
    })
    .css({
      height: $this.prop('scrollHeight')
    });
}

$(".BgChanger").on("click", function() {

  $(".main_textarea")
  .addClass("BgA")
    .css({
      height: 'auto'
    });

});
```

```css
.BgChanger {}

.BgA {
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: green!important;
  text-align: center!important;
  font-size: 22px!important;
  color: white!important;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 50px 20px 40px 20px;
}

.main_textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.main_textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 90px;
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  resize: none!important;
  background: #fff;
  outline: 0;
  color: #292F33 !important;
  font-size: 20px !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="BgChanger">Change Textarea Bg</div>
<textarea class="main_textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: anything I can say you are a genius...have saved me of thousand of years of coding ...setting the `height:auto` is what this code needed to work. Answer definitelly marked! I'm going to edit my question to add the code,,,thank you again.